# Script to run unit test case class in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

Is it possible to run unit test cases only of selected classes in Xcode, I know the way where you can select few classes in the scheme and run them but is there any way to do it through a script.
I wanted to run test cases of only selected classes.

I know the command where you can run selected test cases but I want to run selected classes not the individual test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode's test navigator (Cmd-6 in Xcode 11) will let you run the tests for one class.

Xcode 11's test plans can be run from the command line so you can create a test plan with the classes you want to test and run that test plan in a script. The following article provides an excellent overview of Xcode's test plans:

[Xcode Test Plans](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-test-plans/)

Comment: Thank you so much, this article is really useful.